# UK EU settlment scheme, effects when acquiring British citizenship

Tags: united-kingdom, germany, immigration, poland

I have Polish and German citizenship and passport. My wife the same (she is German originally). But we now live in UK. We need to apply for UK Settlement Scheme, which i think means we will be official residents of 3rd country.

Two questions please:

1. Is this allowed for Poland and Germany? Another residency?
2. We can also apply for UK citizenship. I read in wikpedia that Germany allow if it is EU country. Since UK is still EU if we now apply for UK nationality (which will be 3rd, on top of poland and german / german and polish) will this be allowed by all 3 nations?

Does matter how citizenship is acquired?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

For **Germany** only:

If you make the **application** before the end of the transition period (2020-12-31), then the EU based rules will still apply

- you will be able to retain your German citizenship without a **Retention permit** (Beibehaltungsgenehmigung)

It would therefore be wise to retain a dated confirmation when the application was made.

Any application **after** the 1st of January 2021, a **Retention permit** (Beibehaltungsgenehmigung) must be granted **before** British citizenship has been acquired, otherwise your German citizenship will automatically be lost.

---

> [§ 3 Einbürgerung britischer und deutscher Staatsangehöriger - BrexitÜG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/brexit_g/__3.html)
> ...
> (2) Deutsche, die **vor Ablauf des Übergangszeitraums einen *Antrag* auf Einbürgerung** im Vereinigten Königreich Großbritannien und Nordirland gestellt haben, verlieren ihre deutsche Staatsangehörigkeit nicht nach § 25 Absatz 1 Satz 1 des Staatsangehörigkeitsgesetzes, **auch wenn der Erwerb der britischen Staatsangehörigkeit erst nach Ablauf des Übergangszeitraums erfolgt**.
>
> > (2) Germans who have ***applied* for naturalization** in the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland **before the end of the transition period** do not lose their German citizenship in accordance with Section 25 (1) sentence 1 of the Citizenship Act, **even if the British citizenship is only acquired after the transition period has expired**.

---

**Sources**:

- [§ 3 Einbürgerung britischer und deutscher Staatsangehöriger - BrexitÜG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/brexit_g/__3.html)